# printing lines with more than three fields and the line above

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file such as follows:

```
scaf_1245 457 1
457
scaf_457 784 5
457 4578 784 487 4578
scaf_847 487 4
457 487 487
```

How could I print the lines that have more than three fields (the lines that contain only numbers) with the line above it with awk and grep?

I know:

```
awk 'NF>3' file 

grep -B 1 pattern

Desired output:

scaf_457 784 5
457 4578 784 487 4578
```

but don't know how to combine these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `grep` do it:

```
grep -B1 ".* .* .* .*" file
```

This looks for those lines having at least four blocks of text. Then, `-B1` prints the match and 1 line `B`efore the matched line.

With `awk` you can say:

```
awk 'NF>3 {print f; print} {f=$0}' file
```

It stores the current line in a variable `f` with `f=$0`. Then, when `NF>3` is matched (that is, more than 3 fields in a line), it prints the stored line together with the current one. This can have the problem of printing repeated lines.

For your given file it returns:

```
scaf_457 784 5
457 4578 784 487 4578
```

From `man grep`:

> **-B** NUM, --before-context=NUM
>
> Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines.  Places a
>   line containing a group  separator  (described under
>   --group-separator) between contiguous groups of matches.  With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

Comment: This so cool what you can do with awk but when it comes to these kinds of codes, I am really not able to write them. Is there any advice on how one can learn awk to such degree or does it come only by practice?

Comment: I really like this tutorial: [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/). Apart from that, it is like all the languages: you learn it by practising and, of course, reading good code. Be present in the [awk] tag of [SO] for a while and you will for sure learn a lot, we all do!

Comment: As a side and off-topic note, see you already gained the privilege to upvote. Feel free to do it, as I see in your profile you never did! :)